# bitbucket pipeline keeps running indefinitely

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to set up a remote git pull using a bitbucket pipeline. 
Thinks I have tackled in the first place.

- Connecting to the remote server.

[image]

Now I am running into the problem, that when I command is finished. It is just throwing an error (but the command did work)

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - ssh xx@xxx -tt -p 7685 "ifconfig"
```

What did I do wrong :)?
The pipeline is connection to the remote host, so well that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have an `ifconfig` installed on your remote server. You should either install the `ifconfig` tool or use some other command, for example `ip adress` if your using Debian Linux.

Comment: Hey this seems to fix it.